# JSON.Net example fails

Tags: json.net

Not sure why this fails but here is what I have:

```
    public class Message
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
        public object Body { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchDetails
    {
        public string Query { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
    }

    public void serialize()
    {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.Address = "http://www.google.com";
        message.Body = new SearchDetails
        {
            Query = "Json.NET",
            Language = "en-us"
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message, Formatting.Indented);

    }
```

I get an exception on the SerializeObject: 
"Method not found: 'Boolean System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute.get_IsReference()'."

It's dying in JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType) on InitializeContract(contract);.

What is wrong with my decls?

(thanks in advance)

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I had a similar problem with Newtonsoft.Json when using it with a Windows Phone 7 application.

I had installed using NuGet and the reference it added was to Newtonsoft.Json.Silverlight.

I removed the reference and added Newtonsoft.Json.WindowsPhone instead and it resolved the problem.